# How to convert an exe to text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

what is the encoding required for writing the exe string as if view in notepad  to a text file

```
def read_exe(f_name):
    with open(f_name, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    f.close()

    text_exe = f_name.replace(".exe",".txt")
    with open(text_exe, "w") as h:
        h.write(str(data))
        # tried h.write(data.encoding('utf-8'))
    h.close()

    return
```

as you can see from the commented line I tired to use `utf-8` but it throws an error
I also tried using `ascii`

```
    h.write(data.decode('ascii'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: are you trying to obtain the source code?

Comment: no i want to save exe file as a txt file without doing it manually

Comment: In what way do you want the bytes that are contained in the new file to be different from the bytes that are contained in the old file?

Comment: encoded in a way that i can decode them back for example a nop bytes does not have anything equivalent in ascii as far as i know